# Error when trying to create a Data.List?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a list of type Pos (custom) but keep getting the following error:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `List'
```

Code:

```
import Data.List
type Pos = (Int, Int)
type PlayList = List Pos
```

The error comes up on the line where I define my type PlayList.

Any ideas? Using Haskell in EclipseFP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list type is actually called `[]`, so you'd want

```
type PlayList = [Pos]
```

Although you'll often see people write their own list implementation for playing with various techniques as

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

which is isomorphic to (identical to except for name) the actual implementation of

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Where `Nil == []` and `Cons == (:)`.

Comment: Ok - but this just broke a bunch of code that I guess wouldn't have worked anyways ... how do I add to the HEAD of this? I had the following written "(1,1) : lst" to add to the head of the list, but now I am getting errors (Couldn't match expected type `()'
            with actual type `(Integer, Integer)')

Comment: @JSchwartz It's hard to know without more code.  If you want to add something to the head of a list, you have to make sure that the element is the same type as the other elements in the existing list, and using `:` is the correct way to construct a _new_ list with your element prepended to the front of the old list.  So if `lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4)] :: [(Integer, Integer)`, then `(5, 6) : lst` would return the value `[(5, 6), (1, 2), (3, 4)]`.